# I have a Huge XML File of which I want to read its childtrees into the C++ boost::property_tree::pTree type

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree, readxml

The normal way of doing it is using

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt1;
boost::property_tree::read_xml( XML_FILE_PATH, pt1  );
```

But what this does is that it reads the entire XML File, which is really huge in the pt1

So I think it is inefficient when we just want to read a childTree.

There is another overload function for read_xml which takes in the File Type istream but I don't know how to work with to solve this

```
boost::property_tree::read_xml( iStream, pt1  );
```

Thanks

Comment: How can you validate that the file is correct and have the top-level tag closed if you don't read the whole file? Same with any sub-tree, you need to read until the tag is closed.

Comment: The overloaded function will require you to create a `std::istream` (like `std::ifstream`) but will still read the whole thing